# Почему-то не работает подсветка синтаксиса C# 9.0

Tags: c#, .net-core

Накатил последнюю версию 2019 студии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и в списке появился net 5.0.

Все успешно компилируется, но сама студия подсвечивает новый синтаксис как ошибочный:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Последняя версия языка должна была выбраться студией автоматически:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас проект то под .net 5 успешно работает (запускается)?

Comment: Что будет если явно указать `<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну да запускается.

Comment: @AK будет рекомендовать выставить 9,0 и не стартанет

Comment: Такое впечатление, что анализаторы кода не обновились=(

Comment: А проект новый или изменили версию у ранее созданного? Если второе, то попроуйте его почистить (удалить `.obj`, `bin` и др. директории) а потом запустить студию и нажать "пересобрать". Также лично я ставил SDK и все остально самостоятельно, может вам тоже стоит это сделать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я создавал консольный солюшин с 0. После создания проект появляется с версией 3,0. Я его переключаю на 5.

Comment: SDK пробовал отдельно ставить, но не помогло=(

Comment: Удали кеш вижуалки. Мне кажется дело именно в нем. Ты же обновлял, а не ставил на чистую?

Comment: @Andrew . Да, обновлял. А где кеш живет?

Comment: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache - как-то так

Comment: здесь более полная инструкция: https://www.matteopozzani.com/visual-studio-cache-cleanup/

Comment: Не могу воспроизвести, 16.8.1 - всё работает с консольным приложением.

Comment: @aepot у меня почему-то при создании нового консольного проекта создается для .net core 3.1. А если использовать консольную тулзу, то `<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>`. Подсветка кода в обоих случаях работает нормально.

Comment: @Bulson .Net 5 доступен только в студии версии `16.8` и выше, может из-за этого? Я вчера или когда там еще только выпустили .Net5, поставил все SDK и смотрю, студия не видит его, чтоб я не делал, а оказалось, что они еще не выпустили в тот момент апдейт, который его поддерживал, через пару часов выкатили, поставил и все новые проекты сразу .net5 были.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня версия студии 16.8.1 так что непонятки какие-то... хотя можно после создания проекта подправить руками `<TargetFramework>` и все нормально работает, я проверил уже.

Comment: @Andrew да, чистка кеша помогла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практически наверняка виной всему - кеш вижуалки.
Если ты обновлялся, а не ставил на чистую - там могла остаться закешированной старая подсветка, а но новая не пересоздалась.

Попробуй почистить кеш.

Возможно поможет частичная чистка кеша -- удаление категории `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`

возможно нужна более [злобная чистка](https://www.matteopozzani.com/visual-studio-cache-cleanup/), которую можно найти по запросу в гугле "Visual Studio cache cleanup"

Comment: Cash or cache???