# Silverlight 5 и Visul Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, silverlight

В общем, дело было так:
Все прекрасно работало до тех пор, пока не обновил Visual Studio и не столкнулся с проблемами, когда Visual Studio не понимала синтаксис C# 9.0 и сделал "злобную" чистку из [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1205220/32793) ответа. (Это просто предыстория, как все поломалось и я не хочу заставить дружить Silverlight с Net. Core. Проблемный проект работает на старом фреймворке и со старой версией языка, как и должен)

Сейчас запускаю проект, где есть SIlverLight, а он не работает, хотя ранее работал...

Переустановил [этот](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamiAbughazaleh.SilverlightProjectSystem) плагин, накатил Silverlight_5_Toolkit_December_2011 и Silverlight5_Tools, но нефига...

Почему-то не может найти какие-то референсы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
>     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Data, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35,
> processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
>     <Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Input, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Что я еще должен доустановить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34078020/6808809

Comment: Вы бы потихоньку искали куда съехать с silverlight. Мы как-то обсуждали пару лет назад с коллегами легаси проект, в котором без silverlight было никак и уже тогда было понятно, что надо что-то менять... с тех пор поддержки этой технологии в браузерах всё меньше и меньше и у нас например подгорает куда-то перейти. Вот лучше это делать планово, чем потом в авральном режиме.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ проект не коровый, а на старом фреймворке.

Comment: @AK переходим постепенно, но иногда туда заглядываем.

Comment: `проект не коровый, а на старом фреймворке.` - если в нем вдруг появилась поддержка C# 9, то он уже на новом фреймворке, а точнее, на .NET 5, который явно не имеет поддержи старой, [забрасываемой](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/silverlight-end-of-support-0a3be3c7-bead-e203-2dfd-74f0a64f1788) технологии. Я даже не нашел, чтоб silverlight поддерживался .net core, о какой тогда поддержке .net 5 тут может идти речь? Или я неверно понял ваш посыл и разговор про c# 9 вовсе не связан с этим проектом?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ C# 9.0 вообще не причем. Это предыстория того, как я получил траблы в проекте, где все ранее работало. Там та версия языка, которая и должна быть, не C# 9.0.

Comment: Можно попробовать мигрировать на WPF, и должно заработать. Либо поискать NuGet пакет с нужным набором либ. .NET 5 не поддерживает SilverLight из коробки.